# Report to list new and old user's visits daily, monthly or yearly

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have 2 tables with following table structure -

**Users** (**UserID** int , **Name** varchar(50), **DateCreated** datetime) and

**UserLogin** (**Id** int, **UserId** int, **DateLoggedIn** datetime)

I need to produce a report of users who are logging in to the application every day/month/year in the following format -

**Date, NewUsers, OldUsers, TotalUsers**

**Date** - Date selected for the report

**NewUser** - If the user logs in for the first time in the application, he will be treated as new otherwise as Old User.

**OldUser** - Subsequent user logins after the first visit.

For e.g., if user A logs in on 15th for a month, he will be treated as new user on 15th but as old user for subsequent visits on the website and need to be reported as old user on the report. Similarly if a user B has logged in on 30/4/2012 once, then onward he will be treated as old user.

Can you guys please give me a query to output the report?

My data is as follows -

USER table

```
| UserID |         Name | DateCreated |
|--------|--------------|-------------|
|      1 |      Rajveer |  2012-01-01 |
|      2 |  Manoj Tyagi |  2011-08-10 |
|      3 | Raghu Pandey |  2009-05-13 |
|      4 |   Bhajan Lal |  2012-05-01 |
|      5 | Satbir Singh |  2011-08-03 |
```

USERLOGIN table

```
| ID | UserID | DateLoggedIn |
|----|--------|--------------|
|  1 |      1 |   2012-04-27 |
|  2 |      1 |   2012-05-25 |
|  3 |      1 |   2012-05-28 |
|  4 |      2 |   2012-03-21 |
|  5 |      2 |   2012-05-30 |
|  6 |      3 |   2012-05-20 |
|  7 |      4 |   2012-05-29 |
|  8 |      5 |   2012-04-22 |
|  9 |      3 |   2012-05-15 |
```

I do need entire data for a month (so distinct is not needed)....ideally based on the data i provided, i should get the following

```
| Month | NewUsers | OldUsers | TotalUsers |
|-------|----------|----------|------------|
|     3 |        1 |        0 |          1 |
|     4 |        2 |        0 |          2 |
|     5 |        2 |        4 |          6 |
```

Since user id 3 logged in twice in may, his first visit should be treated as new and second one as old.

TIA,

Paritosh Arya.

Comment: Dou you want to have list of users or just count them (like in @eggyal answer)? If you want the list it would be strange to select OldUsers Newusers and TotalUsers in one select. It is possible but it will result in oakward list and it's better to do 3 selects in my opinion.

Comment: In your sample data, every visit occurs after (in most cases, significantly so) the respective user's `DateCreated`, so on every visit each user is "old" no?  Why are you showing the users as "new" in your sample output?

Comment: The very first time user logs in, I need to show in the report that a new user logged in to the site. Afterwards, the user (having already logged in earlier) becomes the old user and is not unique anymore and hence needs to be listed as Old. This is just the logic of the report I am working on to present data in such a way... So after getting registered, if the user logs in for the first time, the report should say a new user logged in. Any subsequent visit will consider him to be old user

Comment: @user869375: But is it not the case that a user's first login occurs when they register?

Answer (score 0):

You could perform an outer join between the login table and the users table on the join date and then count the distinct user id's in each table:

```
SELECT   DATE(l.DateLoggedIn)                                AS Date,
         COUNT(DISTINCT u.UserID)                            AS NewUsers,
         COUNT(DISTINCT l.UserId) - COUNT(DISTINCT u.UserID) AS OldUsers,
         COUNT(DISTINCT l.UserId)                            AS TotalUsers
FROM     UserLogin                                           AS l
  LEFT JOIN Users                                            AS u
         ON l.UserId = u.UserID
        AND DATE(l.DateLoggedIn) = DATE(u.DateCreated)
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: @user869375: I assumed you only wanted to count users once even if they logged in multiple times on a given day; if that's not the case and you just want to count logins, then remove the `DISTINCT` keywords from each of the `COUNT()` functions.

Comment: looks like i was bit early into coming to a conclusion. When i tested with more data...there was indeed a discrepancy...my data is as follows for 2 tables -

Answer (score 0):

I think this shows the logic but may not have the highest performance.

```
    ;With NewUser as (
        Select ul.UserID
          , Min(ul.DateLoggedIn) as NewDate
        from dbo.USERLOGIN as ul
        group by UserID)

    Select 
      Month(l.DateLoggedIn) as ThisMonth
      , (Select Count(*) from dbo.USERLOGIN as ul 
         inner join NewUser as nu 
         on ul.UserID = nu.UserID
              and ul.DateLoggedIn = nu.NewDate 
         where Month(ul.DateLoggedIn) = Month(l.DateLoggedIn)
        ) as NewUsers
      , (Select Count(*) from dbo.USERLOGIN as ul 
         where Month(ul.DateLoggedIn) = Month(l.DateLoggedIn)
            AND not exists (Select * from NewUser as nu
             where ul.UserID = nu.UserID
                            and ul.DateLoggedIn = nu.NewDate)
        ) as OldUsers
      , Count(*) as TotalUsers
    from dbo.USERLOGIN as l
    group by Month(l.DateLoggedIn)

-- a little testing code
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USERLOGIN](
        [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [USERID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [DateLoggedIn] [date] NOT NULL
    )
    ;
    insert INTO dbo.USERLOGIN 

    select 1, 1, '2012-04-27'
    union all
    Select 2, 1, '2012-05-25'
    union all
    Select  3 , 1,'2012-05-28'
    union all
    Select 4 ,  2,'2012-03-21'
    union all
    Select 5 , 2,'2012-05-30'
    union all
    Select 6 , 3 ,'2012-05-20'
    union all
    Select 7 , 4 ,'2012-05-29'
    union all
    Select 8 , 5,'2012-04-22'
    union all
    Select  9 , 3,'2012-05-15'
```